# Javascript mini Navbar insert

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have an interesting but probably simple problem. I am creating a nav bar insert that has 4 JS buttons that toggle hide a division each, I would like each button to hide the other three divisions while showing the one its own division. Currently each button is only attached to it's own division, I am asking for help that would toggle the other three divs.

Upon further thought I also would like to have the spades, hearts and clubs divs toggled off while the hearts on when a viewer first enters the page.

If you think that there is a better method, I am open to that too, my framework is django jfyi.

Cheers!

JS:

```
// Card Navigation Bar

function dhide() {
    var x = document.getElementById("diamonds");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
function chide() {
    var x = document.getElementById("clubs");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
function hhide() {
    var x = document.getElementById("hearts");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
function shide() {
    var x = document.getElementById("spades");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

html

```
    <button onclick="dhide()">Diamonds</button>
    <button onclick="chide()">Clubs</button>
    <button onclick="hhide()">Hearts</button>
    <button onclick="shide()">Spades</button>

<div id=diamonds>...</div>
<div id=clubs>...</div>
<div id=hearts>...</div>
<div id=spades>...</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about a function that hides them all, then shows the one you want?

js:

```
    function toggleDivs(idToShow){

        document.getElementById("diamonds").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("hearts").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("clubs").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("spades").style.display = 'none';

        document.getElementById(idToShow).style.display = 'block';
    }
    toggleDivs('hearts');
```

html:

```
    <button onclick="toggleDivs('diamonds')">Diamonds</button>
    <button onclick="toggleDivs('clubs')">Clubs</button>
    <button onclick="toggleDivs('hearts')">Hearts</button>
    <button onclick="toggleDivs('spades')">Spades</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rhoteL4t/

Comment: I plugged it in but nothing is happening, all the divs appear when first entering the page and the buttons dont do anything.

Comment: @MoonBoyBlue - This is my mistake. I had omitted the quotations around the display styles. I have edited my answer. I believe it will work now.

Comment: You got it, but one last thing, when I open the page fresh, each div is displayed and then when I click one of the buttons for the first time thats when the other three disappear, is there anyway to hide the three other divs when you first enter the site?

Comment: I have added a fiddle showing my code in action. The hardcoded call toggleDivs('hearts'); right after the function declaration is working for me. Are you including the script in the head of the html? If this is the case the js cannot hide the divs, because they do not exist yet. One way is to include the script at the bottom of the body tag, after the html content.

Comment: You're killing it! because I am running Django, the JS file was being interpreted separately in its own file. I simply included <script language="javascript">toggleDivs('hearts');</script> at the bottom of the html body as you said and it worked like a charm. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could give all of the elements to show/hide the same class.  Then you could do

`document.getElementsByClassName`

to get all of the dom elements you want.  You can then loop through each one and turn it off unless it was the selected id.